# Не отображаются шорткаты, ведущие к другому экрану

Tags: android

На устройстве Android 5.1, Nova Launcher. Не отображаются шорткаты, ведущие к не главному экрану (не MainActivity). Второй активити работает. В чём проблема?

shortcuts.xml

```
        <shortcut
            android:shortcutId="id1"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_shortcut_first"
            android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/first"
            android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/first">
            <intent
                android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                android:targetPackage="country.dev.app"
                android:targetClass="country.dev.app.MainActivity" />
            <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
        </shortcut>
        <shortcut
            android:shortcutId="id2"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_shortcut_second"
            android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/second"
            android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/second">
            <intent
                android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                android:targetPackage="country.dev.app"
                android:targetClass="country.dev.app.SecondActivity" />
            <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
        </shortcut>

</shortcuts>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:resizeableActivity = "true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
            android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />

</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы указываете для SecondActivity android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" в shortcuts.xml, тогда нужно добавить для неё и intent-filter в манифесте:

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Или можно указать вместо android.intent.action.VIEW произвольную строку, например "RANDOM":

```
<shortcut
    android:shortcutId="id2"
    ... >
    <intent
        android:action="RANDOM"
        .... />
    ...
</shortcut>
```